# How to iterate thru multiple values in a single key in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a web app which uses MongoDB as database and I'm trying to iterate thru multiple values inside a single property named passport.

This is my schema:

```
var EmployeeDBSchema = new Schema({

    /* Passport tab schema */
    passportInfo: {
        passportDetails: []
    },
```

And here's how it looks in Robomongo:

[image]

I tried checking if this can be retrieved as an array, so I did below:

```
console.log(_.map(results, _.property('passportInfo')));
passportArr = _.map(results, _.property('passportInfo'));
console.log("is passport array? " + _.isArray(passportArr));
```

**Result:**

[image]

Now since it was positive, I tried iterating thru it like a normal array using the ff. code:

```
 _.forEach(passportArr, function (value, key) {
     _.forEach(passportArr[key], function(value2, key2){
         console.log(key2 + " >> " + value2);
     });
 });
```

However, what I got was this:

[image]

How can I get the values of passportExpiry, passportNumber and countryOfOrigin?

I'm really having a hard time over this. Hoping somebody can help.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Not sure if this will help but, I got the idea for the structure from [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cV2rYVP4Nz8e7wjJdtkR?p=preview). Main idea behind Passport was the user can add an unlimited number of passport information (hence the `passportInfo` array). I'm trying to retrieve the data here so I can render it as a CSV file.

**UPDATE:**
Here's the expanded `results` as requested (from `console.log`):

```
full results
[ { _id: dummyiddontmind123,
    employeeID: '123asd12',
    desiredRoleOther: 'Other role',
    desiredRole3: 'Role 3',
    desiredRole2: 'Role 2',
    desiredRole1: 'The Role',
    isOpenToIntlAssignment: 'Y',
    employeeName: 'Jane Doe',
    yrsInIT: 1,
    visaInfo:
    [ { visaCountryOfOrigin: [Object],
        visaNumber: 'asd',
         visaEntry: 'Single',
         visaExpiry: '2017-03-16T16:00:00.000Z',
         visaStatus: 'expired' } ],
    passportInfo:
    [ { countryOfOrigin: [Object],
         passportNumber: [Object],
         passportExpiry: '2017-03-03' },
       { countryOfOrigin: [Object],
         passportNumber: [Object],
         passportExpiry: '2017-03-08T16:00:00.000Z' },
       { countryOfOrigin: [Object],
         passportNumber: [Object],
         passportExpiry: '2017-03-10T16:00:00.000Z' } ] } ]
    [ [ { passportExpiry: '2017-03-03',
         passportNumber: { '0': 'EB1234567' },
         countryOfOrigin: { '0': 'Philippines' } },
        { passportExpiry: '2017-03-08T16:00:00.000Z',
          passportNumber: { '1': 'AS1234' },
          countryOfOrigin: { '1': 'Japan' } },
        { passportExpiry: '2017-03-10T16:00:00.000Z',
          passportNumber: { '2': 'AX123' },
          countryOfOrigin: { '2': 'Singapore' } } ] ]
```

Comment: There is a difference between your schema and your database : passportInfo is an Object in your schema but it's an Array in your database (according to Robomongo). Is it normal ?

Comment: Could you please paste a full input data set (initial `result` in your example) for people to work with? :)

Comment: Hi @AlexPánek, thanks. Unfortunately I'm not sure if I can paste the complete result here due to privacy reasons at work. The data samples here are just dummies. Fwiw, this is just your ordinary employee db schema; you can just add an `employeeID` property here or something and you're all set. :)

Comment: @BNilsou, I'm not sure myself tbh... This is the very first project I've worked on that uses MongoDB as database.

Comment: Scramble the values in some way, or insert bogus values. Only the structure is important.

Comment: Please see updated question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your data inside `passportInfo` is a bit off, probably due to some copy-paste error after outputting it.
2. I take it you want to export all stored passport information into a `csv` of format `country; number; expiry`.

---

The first thing you want to make sure is that the actual data and the data you expect are structurally the same. If not, you can still add transformation steps before (e.g. flatten arrays or transform objects from `{0: 123}` to `[123]`).

As soon as this is under control, you can start by mapping the objects of `employee.passportInfo` from a structured object to an array of information necessary for your `csv`. This happens using `Array.prototype.map`.

I added another step inside that map to make sure an object of `passportInfo.passportNumber` of the form `{0: 123}` is transformed into an array `[123]`. This array is then used to map to a single line of your `csv` by adding `passportInfo.countryOfOrigin` and `.passportExpiry`.

```js
// The following code snippets only operates on one employee. If you have an array use an iteration function depending on your needs.

const employee = { _id: 123,
  employeeID: '123asd12',
  desiredRoleOther: 'Other role',
  desiredRole3: 'Role 3',
  desiredRole2: 'Role 2',
  desiredRole1: 'The Role',
  isOpenToIntlAssignment: 'Y',
  employeeName: 'Jane Doe',
  yrsInIT: 1,
  visaInfo: [ {
    visaCountryOfOrigin: [Object],
    visaNumber: 'asd',
    visaEntry: 'Single',
    visaExpiry: '2017-03-16T16:00:00.000Z',
    visaStatus: 'expired' }
  ],
  passportInfo: [ {
    countryOfOrigin: 'ABC',
    passportNumber: { 0: '123123123' },
    passportExpiry: '2017-03-03'
  }, {
    countryOfOrigin: 'DEF',
    passportNumber: { 0: '321321321', 1: '123123123' },
    passportExpiry: '2017-03-08T16:00:00.000Z'
  }, {
    countryOfOrigin: 'GHI',
    passportNumber: { 0: '654654654' },
    passportExpiry: '2017-03-10T16:00:00.000Z'
  } ]
};
const flattenPassportNumbers = numbers =>
  Object.keys(numbers).map(key => numbers[key]);
          
const info = employee.passportInfo.map(({passportNumber, passportExpiry, countryOfOrigin}) =>
  flattenPassportNumbers(passportNumber).map(number =>
    [countryOfOrigin, number, passportExpiry]
  )
);

const flattenLine = ([line]) => line; 
const joinLine = (line) => line.join('; ');

const lines = info.map(flattenLine);

console.log(lines.map(joinLine));
console.log(lines.map(joinLine).join('\n'));
```

If there's something you don't understand, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clear (and non-technical) explanation! One question though, what does `=>` do? It's my first time seeing this in JS. Is it a shortcut for converting objects into another type?

Comment: @DeeJ. `=>` is the "arrow syntax" for function literals. See http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies for more information.